# How to Initiate a callout to an eternal system on an event happening in Magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, programmatically

I have a magento2 installed. I would like to know where and what changes do we make to initiate a callout from Magento to the external service with the event details.

e.g Suppose a Product is sold. And I need to send all corresponding information related to this deal to an external system. How would this made be possible. Assuming the external system can be built to accept the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, we can use **Observer** to catch the Magento events. For example, when an order is created successfully. Magento will trigger an event:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php**

```
 public function execute()
 {
        ......

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
 }
```

And then, we take a look at Google Analytics module, we can see how this module tracks the order.

**vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="googleanalytics_order_success" instance="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="multishipping_checkout_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="googleanalytics_order_success" instance="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver" />
    </event>
```

**vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/Observer/SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver.php**

```
 public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
            return;
        }
        $block = $this->_layout->getBlock('google_analytics');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setOrderIds($orderIds);
        }
    }
```